# When is it appropriate to use a dedicated charging ic and when is it appropriate to use a microcontroller?

Tags: batteries, charger

To give a little more context, I am designing a device that requires a battery to be charged. What I gather from most commercial designs and reference designs, is that they often use a dedicated charging chip. Since most of my design directions(philosophy) is copying or implementing what others have, I am constantly concerned that my designs are using far too many parts and/or making the design more complex than necessary.

Additionally, it seems that it would be smarter to design a circuit that uses microcontrollers instead of special ics. In the event that the microcontroller supply or supplier disappears, it would be pretty straightforward to spin up a new revision that uses a new micro. The same can not be said of using a dedicated chip unless it really has barebones functionality.

So in short, what is the logic when deciding to use a dedicated charging chip? Obviously the behavior is well defined and it saves many hours of engineering, but for mass produced devices, it seems as if that would not be an issue.

Comment: This isn't really a question which can have a specific, definitive answer, it seems like it would be a fit for a discussion forum, not but not really for the stackoverflow strict Q/A model.

Comment: This is going to come down to opinion, but it would be interesting to see a number of answers.

Comment: Which batteries, and which MCU? Does the MCU have everything it needs and is accurate enough to charge batteries safely? Does it need much external componets to charge and measure the charging process? Can you implement a bug-free charging algorithm and necessary safety mechanisms so the batteries don't burst into flames if software hangs? Or would you rather just use a dedicated charging chip and concentrate on the actual task instead of spending time so the MCU can charge batteries? It all  depends on what you are making and if you can save money by not using a dedicated charger.

Comment: the battery charging circuit should be a part of the battery module, not part of the device .... that way, the charging circuit can evolve with the battery chemistry

Comment: @jsotola I can think of very few devices (cars, maybe, in fact, maybe a few very fancy power tools) where during the life time of a decade or so you'd offer replacement batteries that are of a different type.

Comment: @jsotola That approach may work for laptops or phones, but in many cases you need to dissipate more heat than could be safely done if the charging circuitry is right next to the battery. Furthermore, it would probably increase the cost of the battery module quite a bit for really little perceivable benefit. If you are using a micro, you can just write new software that adapts to the new chemistry.

Comment: @Justme has the answer.  There's nothing that stops you  from doing a good battery charger with an appropriate choice of microcontroller.  However, code bugs or a processor that hangs for whatever reason could cause a fire or explosion in the case of Li-Ion batteries.  The dedicated chargers have a lot of IP, and generally include watchdog timers and independent safety features.  Also, by the time you add all the peripheral circuitry needed for temperature monitoring, safety, accurate current and voltage measurement, and power path management if may even be cheaper to use a dedicated IC.

Comment: When you need to get something done to a deadline and on budget, use the charging IC. When you have all the time in the world to do the research, build the hardware, write the software, and test it fully, using an MCU is an option.

Answer (score 0):

> So in short, what is the logic when deciding to use a dedicated
> charging chip? Obviously the behavior is well defined and it saves
> many hours of engineering, but **for mass produced devices, it seems**
> **as if that would not be an issue**.

Of course it is an issue. Behavior that is not well defined leads to an unreliable product, which is generally more of an issue for mass produced devices. Engineering cost becomes less important as quantity increases, but still has to be incorporated into the price. Mass produced products are usually more cost-sensitive than 'custom' designs for small markets, and the consequences of a design error may be worse.

In practice, dedicated charger ICs are typically used in low cost devices that don't need a sophisticated charger. They are usually hard-wired to match a particular battery, and have just enough 'smarts' to charge that battery safely and provide the user with basic status information. Examples of this include devices using the [TP4056](https://www.electronicsweekly.com/blogs/engineer-in-wonderland/one-i-missed-tp4056-li-ion-li-po-charger-2019-08/), and 'chargers' that are really just a current limited power supply.

An MCU is appropriate for more expensive devices that need more sophisticated battery management (eg. cell phones, laptop computers), higher voltage and power with greater safety and efficiency (electric cars etc.) or for general purpose chargers which work with a variety of different batteries. It may be combined with a programmable charge controller IC, or with discrete transistors and general purpose ICs.

An MCU may also be used when a dedicated IC for the particular battery type is not available or is more expensive (eg. Nicad and NIMH chargers).

Ultimately it comes down to balancing the cost and convenience of a dedicated IC against the greater flexibility of an MCU based design. Designing a small single cell Li-ion charger using an MCU takes a lot more skill and effort than just throwing a TP4056 at it, but makes sense when the battery is larger, has more cells, or needs better battery management and user feedback. In many cases trying to use a dedicated IC may end op being more difficult and expensive, either due to the extra circuitry required or because it doesn't work reliably.

Comment: Sorry, in my last sentence, I was not clear enough. I meant that for mass produced devices that unreliable behavior and costs can be engineered out and amortized respectively. I have a further question if you could enlighten me. In cases where MCUs are used, do they typically also do any actual regulation, as in voltage and current regulation? Or is that left to dedicated converter(buck, boost, etc) ICs. IT seems to me that the most difficult part of the designing a MCU would be if it needs to also condition the power, since you would basically be reinventing the wheel.